which characters are disallowed in the command for a git alias?
This question Add a Git alias containing a semicolon shows that semicolons in a git alias command need special handling.
But even with the double quotes that answer suggests, I am finding some things don't work.
E.g.:
  related = "!perl -e '$branch = qx[git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD]; ($issue) = $branch =~ m[^(\d+)]; print $issue;'"

produces:

fatal: bad config line 23

What does git dislike with the command?

could you paste your config file? I am not able to reproduce your issue

\d is not a valid escape sequence. You want your alias to contain a backslash followed by a d, therefore you must escape the backslash itself. The following works:
related = "!perl -e '$branch = qx[git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD]; ($issue) = $branch =~ m[^(\\d+)]; print $issue;'"

Or let Git handle the escaping of your alias values by not editing the .gitconfig file manually, but going through the git config command:
git config --global alias.related '!perl -e '\''$branch = qx[git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD]; ($issue) = $branch =~ m[^(\d+)]; print $issue;'\'

(this will produce the same config line as shown above)
